# Selenium IDE button not displaying on Firefox

Tags: firefox-addon, selenium-ide

I am trying to add Selenium IDE 2.9.1.1 add on to Firefox 52. But even after restarting, IDE button is not visible. Downgraded FireFox to 49.0.2 and still facing the issue. I have already added Firebug and FirePath.
Tried some trouble shooting tips I found in Google but no luck. Like downloading IDE from Seleniumhq site etc. Can someone please help me resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to make the Selenium IDE icon appear:

- Open Firefox "Three lines Menu" (**☰** at the right of the icon panel);
- Click "Customize" (hint: Customize the Menu and Toolbars);
- Drag the "Selenium IDE" icon and drop it into the icon panel;
- Restart Firefox.

  - Before: [image: Additional Tools and Features - Drag and drop IDE Icon]
  - After: 
    [image]

You have now two options to open Selenium IDE in Firefox:

1. As a side window, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>;
2. As a separate window

   - by clicking on the Selenium IDE icon;
   - by choosing it at the *Tools* menu or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.   [image]

---

P.S.: Tested with Selenium IDE 2.9.1 and Firefox versions 51.0 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 16.04, and 53.0 (32-bit) on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

- Open Firefox
- Click on the stack icon just below the red "X"
- Click on "Add-Ons"
- Click "Get Add-Ons" on the top left
- Search for Selenium IDE 2.9.1 in the "Search all add-ons" box
- Click on the "Install" button next to the selenium icon
- Firefox will the...[sic]

Comment: Selenium IDE 2.9.1 is not available in the Add on tab in Firefox 49. Only 1.2.0.1 is available which I already tried. As it did not show up, I tried the IDE 2.9.1 available in Seleniumhq.

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded FireFox to 37 and installed add on Selenium IDE 2.9.1.1. This worked.

Comment: But with this, I had issues in running tests in FF as Gecko driver supports only FF 48 and above. Hence I upgraded to FF 49 and it works with Selenium IDE 2.9.1.1